# OpenCV 2.4.8, Python: cannot print SIFT keypoints and descriptors

Tags: python, opencv

I am exploring keypoint matching in OpenCV (version 2.4.8). Trying to print out keypoints and/or descriptors to get better understanding of them:

```
test_img = cv2.imread('../../Downloads/stanford.jpg')

print len(test_img)

detector = cv2.FeatureDetector_create("SIFT")
descriptor = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SIFT")

sskp = detector.detect(test_img)
sskp, ssd = descriptor.compute(test_img, sskp)

print sskp, ssd
```

The code compiles but does not print anything about . Here is the output:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/.../test_sift.py
683

Process finished with exit code 139
```

Here is the "stanford.jpg" image:
http://web.stanford.edu/group/iuc/assets/bg6.jpg

Why `print` does not work here?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not print anything". Because even if those variables were empty strings (which they're unlikely to be), it would at least print a newline. Are you seeing `[] None`? You don't test in any way whether the image was actually loaded (`imread` won't throw an exception) -- are you sure the image was actually loaded?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I have updated the post. The return is: 'Process finished with exit code 139'. I have also tested the image is indeed there.

Comment: Oh, that exit code is significant, that's a segfault. Might be a bug in OpenCV that has been fixed since -- this version is about 2.5 years old. Can you try to upgrade to a more recent version?

Comment: Updating opencv helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan Mašek suggested, apparently this was a bug in the old version of OpenCV. Upgrade to OpenCV 2.4.12 fixed the issue.